# The inverse of a left translation is still a left translation (without the notion of inverse of an element).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $A$ is a nonempty set endowed with an associative binary operation, such that the left and right "translations" by any fixed $a\in A$ (say $\theta_a$ and $\gamma_a$, respectively) are bijections on $A$, then $A$ is a group (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795764/810157) recent post).

If $A$ is finite, it's straightforward to infer the existence of left and right identities (later on proven to be equal) by the closure of the subsets $\Theta:=\{\theta_a, a\in A\}\subseteq \operatorname{Sym}(A)$ and $\Gamma:=\{\gamma_a, a\in A\}\subseteq \operatorname{Sym}(A)$, ensured in turn by operation's associativity; in fact: $\theta_a\theta_b=\theta_{ab}$ and $\gamma_a\gamma_b=\gamma_{ba}$ imply $\Theta,\Gamma\le\operatorname{Sym}(A)$, and thence $\exists\tilde e,\hat e\in A\mid\theta_{\tilde e}=\gamma_{\hat e}=Id_A$. If $A$ is infinite, in order to get the same outcome by using the same approach (subgroup criteria), I'd need to prove also the "closure by inverses", namely:

> $$\forall a\in A, \exists\tilde a \in A\mid \theta_a^{-1}=\theta_{\tilde a} \tag 1$$

I can't figure out how to prove $ (1) $ without the notion of inverse of an element of $ A $, which is obviously not yet available at this stage of the process (existence of the identity). Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't get your question. The post you've linked asks the same question and there's a solution there. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @freakish Yes, it's precisely because the solution is given (so I'm aware that $A$ *is* indeed a group) that I can't figure out why I'm not able to prove it by means of the subgroup criteria for infinite subsets of $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$, which would need of $(1)$ also.

Comment: Well, maybe simply because that idea doesn't work for infinite $A$? You are utilizing the fact that a finite monoid with cancellation property is a group. That is false for infinite monoids as $\mathbb{N}$ shows. I don't see a way to fix that.

Comment: @freakish  That's probably the case. Then I'm wondering how the answer to the linked question "overcomes this all". If you wish, you can put your comment as answer.